# Como puedo hacer conexiones a bases SQL con el lenguaje de programación latino (Sqlite) (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mongodb, sqlite, latino

Estoy usando el lenguaje de programación latino https://lenguajelatino.org/
Y quiero hacer conexiones a bases de datos para seguir mi aprendizaje.
Dado que quiero hacer un proyecto con latino desde el lado del servidor.
Ya logramos comunicarlo con un módulo CGI-BIN.
Dada a esa oportunidad sería genial avanzar un poco más. En esta hermosa misión.
Buen día a todos.
Que tus Proyectos vean la luz.
Y que así sea.

Comment: Este nuevo lenguaje, latino, suena muy interesante, sería genial si posteas alguna otra pregunta y la respondes tu mismo para así compartir tu conocimiento sobre este lenguajes, a la vez que vaya ganando comunidad. Tu podrías ser pionero en el uso de él ;). Puedes leer esto para compartir tu conocimiento: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes conseguir documentacion de realizar conexion MySQL:

https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/Latino-MySQL

Aca tienes un demon para crear una base de datos, insertar en la base de datos consultar algun dato y manimpular datos:

https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/Latino-MySQL/blob/master/ejemplos/demo.lat

Primero incluimos la libreria de MySQL:

```
incluir("mysql")
```

Creamos la la conexion:

```
con = mysql.conectar("localhost", "root", "password", "database")
```

Recordando que el lenguaje no usa (;) punto y coma como es habitual en lenguaje como PHP, Java, C++.

Ejecutar una sentencia seria de la siguiente forma:

```
sql = "select columna from table"
```

Ejecutar la sentencia:

```
resultado = mysql.consultar(con, sql)
```

Para consultar el numero de filas que tiene la consulta:

```
nfilas = mysql.numero_filas(resultado)
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/233001)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Listo amigo ya le agregue informacion, gracias por la sugerencia lo tendre en cuenta para futuro

Answer (score 0):

Para SQLite, la conexión se hace así:

```
incluir("sqlite")

bd = sqlite.conexion_bd("Prueba.db")
```

(Debes reemplazar `Prueba.db` por el nombre de tu archivo sqlite).

En https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/latino-sqlite3 vienen otros detalles además de la conexión: consulta, lectura, etc.